# Bit interleaving in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, c, bit-manipulation

I would like to learn what is bit interleaving.
I have an example:

```
a: 011
b: 101
---
c: 100111
```

As far as I see the bits of the number "a" are on pair positions in the result and the bits of the number "b" are on impair positions.
But why the interleaving starts with number "b"? Do anybody know the rule for this?

I will code the rule in objective-c, so any optimizations connected to this language is very welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe you can read up on [bit interleaving here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interleaving) it's generally done so that interrupted transmissions can be recompiled more easily.  It can be used in A/D to D/A transmissions such as voice over ip.  I believe any bit interleaving with Objective-C will be done in straight C.  [Here](http://homepage.mac.com/chen/Technical/cocoaModem/Implementation/MFSK16/Interleaver/index.html) you can see a de-interleaver example in OBjective-C.  It uses mostly C, and I'm not familiar with any optimizations for it.  Anything Apple uses is likely undocumented.

Comment: For this kind of stuff, the **C** in Objective- **C** is likely going to the focus of the resulting implementation.

Comment: What's an "impair position"? For that matter, what's a "pair position"? Do you mean the corresponding bits of "a" and "b" are paired, with bits of "b" first and "a" second?

Comment: Outis - yes, but maybe I am wrong... this is what I would like to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

```
long x = 3;   // Interleave bits of x and y, so that all of the
long y = 5;   // bits of x are in the even positions and y in the odd;
long long z = 0; // z gets the resulting Morton Number.

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT; i++) {
    z |= (x & 1U << i) << i | (y & 1U << i) << (i + 1);
}
```

This code does the bit interleaving. As you see the result is a morton number.
I hope this will help somebody! :)